# Origin of the phrase "Mustard on the beat"?

Tags: etymology

I have realized that in many rap songs by many different artists use the phrase, ***"mustard on the beat"*** at the begging of their rap.

Where did this originate? Why do many different DJs and rappers use this?

**In my research, I have found this:**

**From** [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DJ_Mustard)

Dijon Isaiah McFarlane (born June 5, 1990), professionally known as DJ Mustard...Almost all of his productions begin or end with the tag "**Mustard on the beat**, hoe!"

But where and why do other rappers, such as 2-Chainz, Kid Ink, and YG just to name a few, use this phrase? What's significant about it's origin?

Comment: Did you read the wikipedia page you cited? Mr McFarlane seems to have had some involvement with the creative output of the performers you mention.

Comment: yes but why other rappers? why not use their own name?

Comment: Can anyone answer that in a logical way that's not in the comments?

Comment: Because he's still the producer of the track, and - from the quote you included in your question - all of the music he produces include that line.

Comment: why him? why that phrase? why is it that it is used by everyone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Often in rap music, the producer is the individual responsible for writing the track's **beat** - the instrumental part of the song that is rapped over.

The producer in question goes by the name DJ Mustard - presumably because his real name is Dijon, and Dijon is [a type of mustard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mustard_(condiment)#Dijon_mustard). The phrase "Mustard on the beat" is used to indicate that DJ Mustard is responsible for writing the beat of the currently-playing track.

This phrase is used by many artists because DJ Mustard has [an extensive production discography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DJ_Mustard_production_discography).

Answer (score -1):

There has been an association between the heat and piquancy of mustard and the zest and energy of people's behavior. This dates back to at least 1672, when the term 'as keen as mustard' is first recorded. 'Up to mustard' or just 'mustard' means up to standard in the same way as 'up to snuff'. 'Cutting' has also long been used to mean 'exhibiting', as in the phrase 'cutting a fine figure'. Unless some actual evidence is found for the other proposed explanations, the derivation of 'cutting the mustard' as an alternative way of saying 'exhibiting one's high standards' is by far the most likely. Applying subjectivity through inference, you could propose "mustard on the beat" means "applying the highest standards or excellence" to the beat.

In laymans  - dat beat is fire, its dope AF, it rides, it bumps, it goes hard.